# Is it possible to combine rigid body and soft body physics in the same object?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

In [blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)?wprov=sfti1) as most of you know there is an option in the animation tab to have soft body and rigid body physics on an object.

On a project that I am currently working on I need soft body on one part of an object and hard on the other, the only problem is, is the fact that it is the same object.

So I guess what I am asking is if it’s possible to do that and if so how?

Comment: I found a similar question that has already been answered here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38579/how-to-have-consistent-soft-body-physics-in-a-specific-area-of-an-object-using-v
The idea is basically to weight paint a vertex group, and effect only that area for the goal. Hope this works for what you are looking for.